# how to use -assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log in my app

Tags: java, android, optimization, proguard

I write `-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log` in my app. but how to use this.

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log 
{
    public static int d(...);
    public static int v(...);
    public static int i(...);
    public static int e(...);
}
```

in `proguard.cfg` file. but not working.

Answer (score 7):

[The manual](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/usage#assumenosideeffects) says `-assumenosideffects` is *"Only applicable when optimizing"*.

`${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt` says: *"Optimization is turned off by default. Dex does not like code run through the ProGuard optimize and preverify steps"*.

http://researcharea.blogspot.com/2012/04/assumenosideeffects-not-working-in.html

Answer (score 4):

According to @Sean Owen and @Yevgen Kulik.

In Gradle, use this:

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

Then add below to your proguard-rules.pro

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log { public * ; }
```

Comment: Using proguard-android-optimize is risky. Checkout the comment in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/master/files/proguard-android-optimize.txt

Comment: There are other approach of removing debug message as per https://medium.com/@elye.project/debug-messages-your-responsible-to-clear-it-before-release-1a0f872d66f#.6io15cj29

Answer (score 3):

Try `-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log { public * ; }`. If that doesn't work, post why you think it isn't working.

Comment: Thanks for that, I had same problem knew wasn't working because a) I have tags that are now showing up in usage since that change, and b) a user submitted a bug from a line. My proguard was slightly different to the OPs

-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
  public static *** d(...);
  public static *** v(...);
}

Answer (score 1):

The below one works exactly

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {

public static *** d(...);

}
```

Similarly you can use i, v and e.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot 'public' access modifier?

```
-assumenosideeffects public class android.util.Log
```