# Android Proguard Options - cannot remove log

Tags: android, proguard, logcat

I tried to follow this post [How to config my proguard-project.txt file to remove just Logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123866/how-to-config-my-proguard-project-txt-file-to-remove-just-logs) but i failed to remove log. I tried for an hours...please help..

I updated android ADT to v22.

For all of below files,

```
\sdk\tools\proguard\proguard-android-optimize.txt
\sdk\tools\proguard\proguard-android.txt
proguard-android.txt of (my android project)
```

I added:

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
public static int v(...);
public static int i(...);
public static int w(...);
public static int d(...);
public static int e(...);
}
```

I then export my app and install to a device. I start my app, and i can still see the log.d line in logcat. What steps do I miss? thank a lot for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in the question that you mention, you should

1. Update `project.properties` in your project, so the configuration path refers to `${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android-optimize.txt` instead of `${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt`. This file enables ProGuard's optimization step, which is the step that can remove logging.
2. Add the `-assumenosideeffects` lines to `proguard-project.txt` in your project.

You probably shouldn't change any files in the Android SDK, since they will get overwritten the next time you update the SDK.