# Proguard does not remove my logs

Tags: java, android, proguard

I want to clear my project from logs, when releasing.
But i'm trying to use proguard and have zero result:
my project settings :

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

# Project target.
target=android-19
android.library.reference.1=..\\google-play-services_lib
```

And my proguard-properties

```
   -optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-keepattributes LineNumberTable
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

#To remove debug logs:
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
    public static *** w(...);
    public static *** i(...);
}


-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.app.ListActivity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keepclassmembers class net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateFragment { 
  *;
}

-keepclassmembers class * { 
    public void onClickUpdate(android.view.View); 
}

-keep public class javax.net.ssl.**
-keepclassmembers public class javax.net.ssl.** {
  *;
}

-keep public class org.apache.http.**
-keepclassmembers public class org.apache.http.** {
  *;
}
```

Why its not work? I'm trying to turn off/on optimization..same result

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use `proguard-android-optimize.txt`, if you want the `assumenosideeffects` settings to work:

Change your proguard.config line to:

> proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android-**optimize**.txt:proguard-project.txt

A more detailed description about `proguard-android-optimize.txt` and `proguard-android.txt` from Eric Lafortune can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123866/how-to-config-my-proguard-project-txt-file-to-remove-just-logs)

Comment: There are some risk using that though. Check out the comment as per https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/master/files/proguard-android-optimize.txt

Comment: There are other approach of removing the debug message, you could find it in https://medium.com/@elye.project/debug-messages-your-responsible-to-clear-it-before-release-1a0f872d66f#.6io15cj29