# proguard doesn't remove logs

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

In **proguard-rules.pro**, I have following configuration:

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
    public static int v(...);
    public static int d(...);
    public static int i(...);
}
```

In my **gradle build**, I enable **proguard** only for **release** build:

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

In MyActivity, I have log code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
   @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d("myTag", "Hello!");
    }
    ...

}
```

I run my app in release build:

[image]

In logcat, I still see the log "Hello!", Why my proguard configuration doesn't remove logs?

Comment: see this hope it help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/21827596/9130109

Comment: you shoud use   proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt').

Comment: Where is `proguard-android-optimize.txt` located? Do I need to create this file & put my configuration there?