# Remove logs using proguard doesn't work

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I've a need to remove all logging from my release App type. I've tried configure proguard to do it for me. My configuration mostly match the one provided in here: [proguard doesn't remove logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50813589/proguard-doesnt-remove-logs) .
I've changed `proguard-android.txt` to `proguard-android-optimize.txt` but with no luck. After going through Proguard manual and checking output of :

```
-whyareyoukeeping class android.util.Log {
   public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
   public static int v(...);
   public static int i(...);
   public static int w(...);
   public static int d(...);
   public static int e(...);
   public static int wtf(...);
}
```

learned that this couldn't be removed because of:

```
Explaining why classes and class members are being kept...
Printing usage to [...]...
android.util.Log
  is a library class.
android.util.Log: boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String,int)
  is a library method.
android.util.Log: int v(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
  is a library method.
android.util.Log: int v(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Throwable)
  is a library method.
android.util.Log: int i(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
  is a library method.
android.util.Log: int i(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Throwable)
  is a library method.
android.util.Log: int w(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
  is a library method.
android.util.Log: int w(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Throwable)
  is a library method.
android.util.Log: int w(java.lang.String,java.lang.Throwable)
  is a library method.
android.util.Log: int d(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
  is a library method.
android.util.Log: int d(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Throwable)
  is a library method.
android.util.Log: int e(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
  is a library method.
android.util.Log: int e(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Throwable)
  is a library method.
android.util.Log: int wtf(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
  is a library method.
android.util.Log: int wtf(java.lang.String,java.lang.Throwable)
  is a library method.
android.util.Log: int wtf(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Throwable)
  is a library method.
```

What could be reason for that? Maybe some other Proguard option? Is there any other option to enforce logs removal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of Guardsquare support I've been able to find out problem. One of libraries has **-dontoptimize** in its ProGuard config file. Helpful to narrow down this issue is option **-printconfiguration [filename]**

Doc. for ref - https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/usage#generaloptions

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that ProGuard should remove these logging calls using a configuration like that:

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log 
{
    public static int d(...);
    public static int v(...);
    public static int i(...);
    public static int e(...);
}
```

Keep in mind that you need optimization to be enabled to actually remove these calls. For this use this default configuration:

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')
```