# ProGuard: ClassCastException

Tags: java, gson, proguard, obfuscation

I'm getting this annoying `ClassCastException` when I obfuscate my Java code (which works fine before I obfuscate using `ProGuard`).

```
   java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.StringMap cannot be cast to net.minecraft.launcher.profile.Profile
        at java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.StringMap cannot be cast to net.minecraft.launcher.profile.Profile
at net.minecraft.launcher.profile.ProfileManager.getSelectedProfile(SourceFile:117)
at net.minecraft.launcher.g.run(SourceFile:184)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

That ClastCastException error points to this bit of code, here (the bolded line being the exact line):

```
public Profile getSelectedProfile()
{
    if ((this.selectedProfile == null) || (!this.profiles.containsKey(this.selectedProfile))) {
        if (this.profiles.get("Default") != null)
        {
            this.selectedProfile = "Default";
        }
        else if (this.profiles.size() > 0)
        {
            this.selectedProfile = ((Profile)this.profiles.values().iterator().next()).getName();
        }
        else
        {
            this.selectedProfile = "Default";
            this.profiles.put("Default", new Profile(this.selectedProfile));
        }
    }
    *Profile profile = this.profiles.get(this.selectedProfile);*
    return profile;
}
```

Whole Class File (Un obfuscated) : http://pastebin.com/Jgh4x1SS
`RawProfileList` Class File (Un obfuscated) : http://pastebin.com/vPxFpYfC
`ProGuard` version : 5.2.1

Declaration of Profiles field:

```
private final Map<String, Profile> profiles = new HashMap<String, Profile>();
```

Comment: Please show us the declaration of `selectedProfile` and `profiles` fields. Also if it's possible, please provide a non-obfuscated and obfuscated `.class` file. And which version of ProGuard are you using?

Comment: Added to bottom of post. 

Whole Class File (Un obfuscated) : http://pastebin.com/Jgh4x1SS
ProGuard version : 5.2.1
Declaration of Profiles field:
private final Map<String, Profile> profiles = new HashMap<String, Profile>();

Comment: Who writes in the `profiles` map? I suspect there is something in the Minecraft framework that uses reflection to decide what to populate your map with, and since the names have changed, it behaves differently with the obfuscated code.

Comment: Show us the `RawProfileList` class.

Comment: @biziclop if you look in this class (http://pastebin.com/Jgh4x1SS) the loadProfiles uses gson's fromJson method to set rawProfile's profiles to the values. RawProfileList class = http://pastebin.com/Jgh4x1SS

Comment: That's where I would start looking then. If you're getting a class cast exception when getting a value from a map, always look at the put, that's where the problems are likely to be.

Comment: Does your `proguard.cfg` contain [these rules](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg)?

Comment: @EgorN Not all of it, only some. This is my proguard config file: http://pastebin.com/68gec9uG

Comment: @EgorN It worked!!!  don't know how, but it did. I'm curious to know how it worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your classes look fine. `ClassCastException` means that `Gson` didn't know that a field should have been serialized as `Profile`.

Make sure your `proguard.cfg` contains all of [these rules](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg).

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @EgorNeliuba's excellent answer, as [these rules](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg) **alone** were insufficient in my situation:

1. `MyPrettyAmazingDataStruct` is fully serialized and instantiated from a corresponding JSON in **debug** mode.
2. `MyApp` is using `MyCoreLib`, hence 2 `build.gradle` files and 2 `proguard.cfg` files.

My ordeal started when my APK started crashing with:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: e2.s cannot be cast to com.me.mycorelib.MyPrettyAmazingDataStruct
```

I checked `mapping.txt` and the only obfuscation to `e2.s` is:

```
com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap -> e2.s
```

**Note**: Getting Logcat to log messages from a Proguard-processed APK was an ordeal by itself because I did not know that the [-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22774371/3154666) should be **commented out** in MyApp's proguard.cfg **as well**. It is not enough to do so in MyCoreLib's proguard.cfg **only**.

So, I naively added to **both** proguard.cfg files the following:

```
-keep public class com.me.mycorelib.MyPrettyAmazingDataStruct
-keepnames class  com.me.mycorelib.MyPrettyAmazingDataStruct
-keepclassmembers class com.me.mycorelib.MyPrettyAmazingDataStruct
```

That did not eliminate the exception.

Then I found @EgorNeliuba's answer which added [these rules](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg) (to **both files!**) and now MyApp is no longer crashing.

Lastly, it was helpful for me to finally understand the differences between:

| Option | Class Name | Class Code | Member Name | Member Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -keep | Preserved | Preserved | Preserved | Preserved |
| -keepnames | Preserved | Optimized | Preserved | Optimized |
| -keepclassmembers | Optimized | Optimized | Preserved | Preserved |

Please correct the above table if you spot any mistake.