# ProGuard makes Gson return LinkedTreeMap instead of my type

Tags: java, android, gson, kotlin, proguard

The following line of code works for me normally:

`val users: Array<Catalog> = com.google.gson.Gson().fromJson(data, Array<MyUserClass>::class.java)`

But when I enable ProGuard, I get this error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap
>   cannot be cast to com.example.app.Models.MyModel

`MyUserClass` is as follows:

`data class MyUserClass(var posts: List<UserPosts>)`

So Gson properly makes `users` be `MyUserClass` - but instead of `MyUserClass` being a list of `UserPosts`, it ends up being a list of `LinkedTreeMap`

I've been trying to solve this for a while now, and all the answers I found related to this have to do with generics, but I'm not using generics, I'm passing the class directly to Gson.

I'm completely lost at this point, so any guidance would be apprecciated

Here's the related ProGuard rules:

```
##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }

-keep class com.example.Models.** { *; }

# Prevent proguard from stripping interface information from TypeAdapterFactory,
# JsonSerializer, JsonDeserializer instances (so they can be used in @JsonAdapter)
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer
##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------

-keep public class MyUserClass
-keep public class UserPosts
```

Comment: Are you sure you have all proguard rules set?

Comment: can you try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30138142/1754020

Comment: I am not, this is my first time with ProGuard, so I could have messed up. Updated answer

Comment: Oh man...I had `-keep class com.example.Models.** { *; }` instead of `-keep class com.example.app.Models.** { *; }`  Thank you both for mentioning ProGuard rules! I wouldn't have looked over them again otherwise :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your proguard.cfg contains all of the rules:

```
    ##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }

# Prevent proguard from stripping interface information from TypeAdapterFactory,
# JsonSerializer, JsonDeserializer instances (so they can be used in @JsonAdapter)
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
-keep public class MyUserClass
-keep public class UserPosts
```

Comment: Thanks again for making me check back over the rules, it ended up being a typo on my part, but it still helped!