# Android Proguard error with org.apache.http

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I am using proguard for secure signed apk it is fine when i use **proguard-android.txt** file. But when i use **proguard-android-optimize.txt** for logcat hide it give me error while generating signed apk the error was

> ```
> Unexpected error while performing partial evaluation:
>   Class       = [org/apache/http/impl/conn/BasicClientConnectionManager]
>   Method      = [getConnection$219f236b(Lorg/apache/http/conn/routing/HttpRoute;)Lorg/apache/http/conn/ManagedClientConnection;]
>   Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Can't find common super class of [org/apache/http/impl/conn/HttpPoolEntry] (with
> ```
>
> 1 known super classes) and [org/apache/http/conn/routing/HttpRoute]
>   (with 2 known super classes))

My proguard-rules.pro file is

```
    #Removing log cat
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
    public static int v(...);
    public static int i(...);
    public static int w(...);
    public static int d(...);
    public static int e(...);
}

#Httplibrary
-dontwarn org.apache.**
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontnote android.net.http.*
-dontnote org.apache.commons.codec.**
-dontnote org.apache.http.**
-keep public class org.apache.http.**{
                    public protected *;
                    }


-keep interface org.apache.http.**

# OrmLite uses reflection
-keepattributes Signature

-keep class com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers class com.j256.** { *; }
-keep enum com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers enum com.j256.** { *; }
-keep interface com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers interface com.j256.** { *; }

-keepclassmembers class com.j256.** {
  public *;
}
-keep public class com.j256.ormlite.**{
            public protected *;
            }
-keep public class * extends com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper
-keep public class com.nacheepa.nacheepa.database.DBOpenHelper
-keepattributes *Annotation*

#Other app
-keep public class com.android.volley.**{
                         public protected *;
                                          }
-keep public class android.support.v7.**{
                         public protected *;
                                          }

-keep public class android.support.design.**{
                        public protected *;
                                          }
-keep public class android.support.v4.**{
                         public protected *;
                                          }

-keep public class com.nacheepa.nacheepa.**{
                       public protected *;
                                           }

-keep public class com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.**{
                         public protected *;
                                          }

-keep public class uk.co.senab.photoview.**{
                    public protected *;
                                           }

-keep public class de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.**{
                     public protected *;
                                                  }

-keep public class com.sithagi.countrycodepicker.**{
                      public protected *;
                                                   }

-keep public class com.nostra13.universalimageloader.**{
                       public protected *;
                                                       }
```

Guide me to write valid rules for proguard as i am first time using proguard
Thanks!

Comment: I think following thread will be of worth for you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22714626/my-log-messages-are-not-removed-with-proguard-configuration

Comment: try to add -keep class org.apache.http.**

Comment: @sonnv1368 after adding your line , i am getting the same error

Comment: You can read this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32596858/proguard-and-error