# Is proguard-android.txt obsolete?

Tags: android, proguard

Up until not too long ago, I followed the guideline that *"In general, it is a good idea to use the `proguard-android.txt` file as the default proguard file and then add any additional rules that you need in a separate file, such as `proguard-rules.txt`."*

However, I just (*Android Studio 2022.2.1 Patch 2, Gradle 8.0.2*) noticed the first comment in `proguard-android.txt` which says:

```
# This file is no longer maintained and is not used by new (2.2+) versions of the
# Android plugin for Gradle. Instead, the Android plugin for Gradle generates the
# default rules at build time and stores them in the build directory.
```

How does this change the relevant entry in `build.gradle`?

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
```