# Proguard in Android Studio are not removing logging

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard

Using Android Studio 1.2 beta, Proguard 4.7, I'm not able to optimize (remove) **Log.d**.

Using the tools **d2j-dex2jar** and **jd-gui** I can see that all the Log.d remains in the apk.

Any wise comments on this problem?

The **proguard-rules.pro** are used because the **-dontwarn** are working.

My **proguard-rules.pro**:

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** v(...);
    public static *** i(...);
    public static *** w(...);
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** e(...);
}

-dontwarn com.google.common.**
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontwarn javax.inject.**
-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe
-dontwarn org.joda.time.**
```

Answer (score 1):

From [How to config my proguard-project.txt file to remove just Logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123866/how-to-config-my-proguard-project-txt-file-to-remove-just-logs)

Replace:
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

with:
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

Comment: Doing this seems risky. Check the comment on top of the file at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/master/files/proguard-android-optimize.txt.

Comment: There are other approach of removing debug messages, do check out this blogpost https://medium.com/@elye.project/debug-messages-your-responsible-to-clear-it-before-release-1a0f872d66f#.6io15cj29

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
    public static int v(...);
    public static int i(...);
    public static int w(...);
    public static int d(...);
    public static int e(...);
}
```

Comment: copy-pasted your setup, but it is still not working :( Have you tried to reverse-engineered your apk to verify that Log is removed?